# Date comparison in where clause of sql stored procedure

Tags: c#, t-sql, stored-procedures

Could please anyone tell me how I can do the date comparison in where clause of a sql stored procedure.

I have a provided a text box filter to the user where user can enter date in any format (e.g. 13/09/2013, 13092013, 13-Sep-2013, 130913). The DB table has datetime type column on which I want to apply this filter to.

Here I have 3 questions

1. Do I have to convert it to some specific date only type in my c# code first. IF yes than does the date format matter?
2. How to check if the date type parameter is not null or empty?
3. How I will compare the above date only type (from c# code) with datetime column of my DB table?

A code example will really be appreciated.

Kind Regards

Comment: I have placed an IF condition as follow IF(NULLIF(@CompanyName, '') IS NULL AND NULLIF(@DateOfEnquiry, '') IS NULL) now I have to apply the date comparason in where clause. Here I am not sure if my IF statement is right also, how to get the date part only from @DateOfEnquiry and my table.DateOfEnquiry and apply comparison to it

Comment: That IF condition looks weird: NULLIF-check on @CompanyName replaces any NULL within that variable with '', so that can never be NULL. After that comes "IS NULL". So You check wether something IS NULL that can never be NULL. There is the same problem with DateOfEnquiry. I think that doesn't help with any requirement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers:

(1). You should force user to enter in a CERTAIN FORMAT. If you don't know the entering format, how do you know if `12-11-2013` 12th of November or 11th of December? This is just a one example.

If you know the user entering format, you can either convert it to a date in the code or pass as a string in ISO FORMAT (`yyyymmdd`) into the stored procedure.

First method would be better as if the user input is not a valid date then you could stop calling the stored procedure.

(2). Your code behind receives the user input as a string. So you can check it in code behind like;

```
 bool isNull = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userEnteredDate);
```

(3). in your stored procedure

```
 --Rest of the query
 WHERE Convert(date, yourdateColumn) = @yourDateParameter
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kaf for your detailed explaination. I really appreciate your help. You really have made my life easier.